# How do I make a custom button in Android inherit the element's attributes?

Tags: android, xml

First, I created the Java class:

```
public class CheckedButton extends Button {
    private static final int[] STATE_CHECKED = { R.attr.state_checked };

    private boolean mChecked = false;
```

Then, I added the custom element to the activity XML:

```
<com.example.myapp.CheckedButton
    android:id="@+id/button_q"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:onClick="clickLetter"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Q"
    style="@style/checked_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_w"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_w"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_200"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:onClick="clickLetter"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="W"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_e"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_q"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="checked_button" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    </style>
</resources>
```

The thing is that no matter how I try, it seems impossible for my CheckedButton to have the same dimensions and colors as Button. How can I inherit the "attributes" of Button?

I have been at this for about a week now, trying ToggleButton solutions, .setBackgroundColor() and .setBackgroundTintList() hacks, tried a style.xml in res/values, checked_button.xml in res/drawable, messed around with colors and custom states and nothing works well.

All I want to do is add an extra state to a button and when I toggle it, change its background color WITHOUT destroying the background colors for all other states. Most examples out there show how to make a custom button, but then I must create the entire element XML from scratch. Why can't I inherit the Button attributes?

I mean, I could just keep the states of all buttons in variables and toggle their background colors with Java code, but isn't there a smoother solution?

Even that purple tint is an experiment that didn't work out. The default background color of Button is blue (and that's what CheckedButton should be as well). The white textColor for CheckedButton is from the style.xml file - otherwise it's RED, which is also not inherited from Button.

[image: Difference between CheckedButton and Button]

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions aren't set by the style.  In fact they *can't* be set by the style.  Dimensions are set by the layout_width and `layout_height`.  For the case in your picture here, you could probably set the height to wrap_content for the first button and `fill_parent` for the second and it would work properly.  If you're in a constraint or relative layout, you could also us a `layout_align_bottomToBottomOf` on the checkbox setting it to align to the button's bottom.

Secondly, adding a state to a button-  don't do that.  You're better off using a checkbox with a custom drawable that displays it how you want.  Buttons don't have a state other than pressed state, checkboxes do.  Or write a custom view if you prefer.  But you're pretty much fundamentally changing how Button works and the default drawable for button won't have a checked state so it won't work properly.  It will be easier to write it all yourself based off of TextView than it would be to force button to do that.

If you do use checkbox, you can supply it with a custom drawable that will do most of the work.  Drawables can have different displays for different states.  One of those states is CHECKED.  Checkbox works with that.  That would be the easiest way to do it-  work with the drawable system. Just create a custom state list drawable in xml, and set the various states as you want them.  The important one is CHECKED, but PRESSED also matters for the touching animation.

ToggleButton could also work.  It isn't 100% what you want, but it can be massaged into it.  It also takes a drawable that works with the CHECKED state.

Comment: Thanks, I have considered using other elements, but I still want the appearance (with all effects) of a button. Is there any way to copy that? I know I can create custom whatevers from scratch, but if I must, I'd rather code Java and use a standard button.

Comment: The drawable used by Button is open source.  (the drawable is how the button has the effects it does).  There's actually 0 new code in Button's draw function, it's just a TextView with a custom drawable (see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/Button.java).  You could copy that drawable and add a checked state, then use it for your custom view.  (Actually its very common not to use Button at all, a lot of things end up just being touchable text views).

Comment: Btw the standard touch behavior drawable is called the ripple, if you just want to use it directly.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions. Since I couldn't figure out how to use the appearance/style/drawable of a Button on any other element, I created a Keyboard class that changes the background colors of regular buttons as needed. It's ugly, but works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To make a custom button in Android inherit the element's attributes, you can create a custom view that extends an existing Android button class (e.g., AppCompatButton) and use custom attributes in XML to set the properties for the custom view. Here's how you can explain the process based on the provided solution:

1. **Define Custom Button Class:**
   Create a custom button class by extending an existing Android button class. For example, you can create a class called "**CustomButton**" that extends "**AppCompatButton**":

```
class CustomButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    // Custom button logic and styling can be added here
}
```

2. **Define Custom Attributes in attrs.xml:**
   In your "**attrs.xml**" file, define custom attributes for your "**CustomButton**":

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomButton">
    <attr name="btn_type" format="enum">
        <enum name="custom" value="0" />
        <enum name="primary" value="1" />
        <enum name="alert" value="2" />
        <enum name="simple" value="3" />
    </attr>

    <attr name="view_type" format="enum">
        <enum name="fill" value="0" />
        <enum name="border" value="1" />
        <enum name="link" value="2" />
    </attr>

    <attr name="font_type" format="enum">
        <enum name="bold" value="0" />
        <enum name="medium" value="1" />
        <enum name="regular" value="2" />
    </attr>

    <attr name="font_color" format="enum">
        <enum name="none" value="0" />
        <enum name="regular" value="1" />
        <enum name="primary" value="2" />
        <enum name="title" value="3" />
        <enum name="title_black" value="4" />
        <enum name="text" value="5" />
        <enum name="hint" value="6" />
        <enum name="required" value="7" />
        <enum name="error" value="8" />
        <enum name="white" value="9" />
    </attr>

</declare-styleable>
```

3. **Implement Custom Logic:**
   Inside your "**CustomButton**" class, you can read and apply the custom attributes to customize the button's behavior and appearance. For example, you can use the "**btn_type**", "**font_type**", and "**view_type**" attributes to determine the button's style and behavior.
4. **Usage in XML Layout:**
   In your XML layout, you can use the **CustomButton**" like any other view. Set the custom attributes to define the appearance and behavior of the button:

```
<com.yourpackage.CustomButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Custom Button"
    app:btn_type="custom"
    app:font_type="bold"
    app:view_type="fill" />
```

In this example, we're using a '**CustomButton**' and setting its custom attributes to specify that it should be a custom-styled button, use bold font, and have a filled background.

By following these steps, you can create a custom button that inherits the specified attributes from the XML layout and use these attributes to style and customize the button's appearance and behavior.

Here's a full example of a custom button class based on your code, along with a short description of the class and its usage:

**CustomButton.kt**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.actionlogger.BuildConfig
import com.actionlogger.R
import com.actionlogger.enums.button.ButtonTypeEnum
import com.actionlogger.enums.button.ButtonViewEnum
import com.actionlogger.enums.text_view.FontColorEnum
import com.actionlogger.enums.text_view.FontTypeFaceEnum
import com.actionlogger.utils.extensions.default
import com.actionlogger.utils.extensions.fromHtml
import com.actionlogger.utils.extensions.underLine
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.io.StringWriter

class CustomButton(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : AppCompatButton(context, attrs) {

    private var viewType = ButtonViewEnum.BORDER
    private var fontColorEnum : FontColorEnum?=null

    init {
        init(attrs)
    }

    private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        attrs?.let { applyCustomProperty(it) }
    }

    private fun applyCustomProperty(attrs: AttributeSet) {
        val typedArray = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomButton, 0, 0)
        try {

            viewType = ButtonViewEnum.values()[typedArray.getInt(
                R.styleable.CustomButton_view_type,
                ButtonViewEnum.BORDER.id()
            )]

            val fontEnum = FontTypeFaceEnum.values()[typedArray.getInt(
                R.styleable.CustomButton_font_type,
                FontTypeFaceEnum.REGULAR.id()
            )]


            val typeEnum = ButtonTypeEnum.values()[typedArray.getInt(
                R.styleable.CustomButton_btn_type,
                ButtonTypeEnum.PRIMARY.getID()
            )]

            fontColorEnum = FontColorEnum.values()[typedArray.getInt(
                R.styleable.CustomButton_font_color,
                FontColorEnum.PRIMARY.id()
            )]


            setFontType(fontEnum)
            if (isLinkButton()) setLinkButton(fontColorEnum?:FontColorEnum.PRIMARY)
            else setButtonType(typeEnum)

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                val sw = StringWriter()
                val pw = PrintWriter(sw)
                e.printStackTrace(pw)
            }
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            typedArray.recycle()
        }
    }

    private fun isFillButton() = viewType == ButtonViewEnum.FILL
    private fun isLinkButton() = viewType == ButtonViewEnum.LINK

    private fun setFontType(enum: FontTypeFaceEnum) {
        enum.font(context).let { typeface = it }
    }

    fun setViewType(viewType: ButtonViewEnum) {
        this.viewType = viewType
    }

    fun setButtonType(typeEnum: ButtonTypeEnum) {
        when (typeEnum) {
            ButtonTypeEnum.PRIMARY -> setPrimaryButton()
            ButtonTypeEnum.ALERT -> setAlertButton()
            ButtonTypeEnum.SIMPLE -> setSimpleButton()
            ButtonTypeEnum.CUSTOM -> setFontColor(fontColorEnum?:FontColorEnum.PRIMARY)
        }
    }

    private fun setPrimaryButton() {
        background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            context,
            if (isFillButton()) R.drawable.button_ripple_primary_fill else R.drawable.button_ripple_primary_border
        )
        setTextColor(
            ContextCompat.getColor(
                context,
                if (isFillButton()) R.color.colorWhite else R.color.colorPrimary
            )
        )
    }

    private fun setAlertButton() {
        background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            context,
            if (isFillButton())R.drawable.button_ripple_alert_fill else  R.drawable.button_ripple_alert_border
        )
        setTextColor(
            ContextCompat.getColor(
                context,
                if (isFillButton()) R.color.colorWhite else R.color.colorLightRed
            )
        )
    }

    private fun setSimpleButton() {
        background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            context,
            if (isFillButton()) R.drawable.button_ripple_simple_fill else R.drawable.button_ripple_simple_border
        )
        setTextColor(
            ContextCompat.getColor(
                context,
                if (isFillButton()) R.color.colorWhite else R.color.colorGray
            )
        )
    }

    fun setLinkButton(enum: FontColorEnum) {
        background = null
        text = text.toString().default().underLine().fromHtml()
        setFontColor(enum)
    }

    fun setText(name:String) {
        text = name.default().underLine().fromHtml()
    }

    fun setFontColor(enum: FontColorEnum) {
        if (enum != FontColorEnum.NONE) setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, enum.color()))
    }


}
```

**ButtonViewEnum.kt**

```
enum class ButtonViewEnum {
    FILL,
    BORDER,
    LINK;

    fun id() = when (this) {
            FILL -> 0
            BORDER -> 1
            LINK -> 2
        }

    fun enum(id: Int) =  when (id) {
            0 -> FILL
            2 ->  LINK
            else -> BORDER
        }
}
```

**FontColorEnum.kt**

```
import com.actionlogger.R

enum class FontColorEnum {
    NONE,
    REGULAR,
    PRIMARY,
    TITLE,
    TITLE_BLACK,
    TEXT,
    HINT,
    REQUIRED,
    ERROR,
    WHITE;

    fun id() = when (this) {
        NONE -> 0
        REGULAR -> 1
        PRIMARY -> 2
        TITLE -> 3
        TITLE_BLACK -> 4
        TEXT -> 5
        HINT -> 6
        REQUIRED -> 7
        ERROR -> 8
        WHITE -> 9
    }

    fun color() = when (this) {
        NONE -> 0
        REGULAR -> R.color.colorGray
        PRIMARY -> R.color.colorPrimary
        TITLE -> R.color.colorProfileTitle
        TITLE_BLACK -> R.color.colorBlackText
        TEXT -> R.color.colorGrayAlpha
        HINT -> R.color.colorGrayHint
        REQUIRED -> R.color.colorRedDark
        ERROR -> R.color.colorLightRed
        WHITE -> R.color.colorWhite
    }

    fun enum(id: Int) = when (id) {
        0 -> NONE
        1 -> REGULAR
        2 -> PRIMARY
        3 -> TITLE
        4 -> TITLE_BLACK
        5 -> TEXT
        6 -> HINT
        7 -> REQUIRED
        8 -> ERROR
        9 -> WHITE
        else -> REGULAR
    }

}
```